# Struct and dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm new in c and sorry for my poor English.

I'm trying to write a program that ask to user if he want enter data (region, date of detection, mm of rain) using keyboard and save it in file or if he want give it file's name.
No problem at this time and file is written or read correctly.
File have this structure:

```
Texas 03/03/2015 1
California 06/02/2013 5
Utah 03/01/2014 10
....
```

Try with scanf() (not report main because there is no problem in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef enum mese_e {Gen=1, Feb, Mar, Apr, Mag, Giu, Lug, Ago, Set, Ott, Nov, Dic} tipo_mese;
typedef struct data_s
{
    int giorno;
    tipo_mese mese;
    int anno;
} tipo_data;

typedef struct dati_file_s
{
    char* regione;
    tipo_data data;
    int mm_pioggia;
} tipo_dati_file;

typedef struct ritorna_s
{
    tipo_dati_file* array;
    int count;
} tipo_ritorna;

int conta_righe(char* Nome_f)
{
    int i=0;
    char c;
    FILE* file;
    file=fopen(Nome_f,"r");
    while ((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF)
    {if(c=='\n')
    i++;}
    fclose(file);
    return i;

}
void crea_array (char* Nome_f)
{
    int i,n;
    char* regione= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    tipo_data data;
    int mm_pioggia;
    tipo_ritorna risultati;
    FILE* file;
    n = conta_righe(Nome_f);
    printf("%d\n",n);
    tipo_dati_file* array = (tipo_dati_file*) malloc (n*sizeof (tipo_dati_file));
    file = fopen(Nome_f,"r");
    if( file==NULL )
        {
            printf("Errore in apertura del file!");
            exit(1);
        }
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file,"%s %d/%d/%d %d\n",regione, &data.giorno, &data.mese, &data.anno, &mm_pioggia);
        strcpy(array[i].regione, regione);
        array[i].data.giorno=data.giorno;
        array[i].data.mese= data.mese;
        array[i].data.anno= data.anno;
        array[i].mm_pioggia= mm_pioggia;
        printf("%s %d/%d/%d %d\n",array[i].regione,array[i].data.giorno, array[i].data.mese,array[i].data.anno,array[i].mm_pioggia);
        }

    fclose(file);
}
```

try with fgets()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> typedef enum mese_e {Gen=1, Feb, Mar, Apr, Mag, Giu, Lug, Ago, Set, Ott, Nov, Dic} tipo_mese; typedef struct data_s {
    int giorno;
    tipo_mese mese;
    int anno; } tipo_data;

typedef struct dati_file_s {
    char* regione;
    tipo_data data;
    int mm_pioggia; } tipo_dati_file;

typedef struct ritorna_s {
    tipo_dati_file* array;
    int count; } tipo_ritorna;

int conta_righe(char* Nome_f) {
    int i=0;
    char c;
    FILE* file;
    file=fopen(Nome_f,"r");
    while ((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF)
    {if(c=='\n')
    i++;}
    fclose(file);
    return i;

} void crea_array (char* Nome_f, int v) {
    int i=0,s;
    char* r;
    //tipo_ritorna risultati;
    FILE* file;
    //n = conta_righe(file);
    tipo_dati_file* array = (tipo_dati_file*) malloc (v*sizeof (tipo_dati_file));
    file = fopen(Nome_f,"r");

    if( file==NULL )
        {
            printf("Errore in apertura del file!");
            exit(1);
        }
    if (feof(file)==0)
    {
        char* buf= (char*) malloc(v*sizeof(char));
        /*while ( fgets( buf,10000, file) != NULL )
        {
            r = sscanf( buf, "%s% d/%d/%d %d\n", array[i].regione, &array[i].data.giorno, &array[i].data.mese, &array[i].data.anno, &array[i].mm_pioggia);
            printf("%s %d/%d/%d %d\n", array[i].regione, array[i].data.giorno, array[i].data.mese, array[i].data.anno, array[i].mm_pioggia);
            i++;
        }*/
        while(1)
        {
            r=fgets( buf,1000, file);
            if (r!=NULL)
            {
                printf("%s",buf);
                sscanf( buf, "%s% d/%d/%d %d\n", array[i].regione, &array[i].data.giorno, &array[i].data.mese, &array[i].data.anno, &array[i].mm_pioggia);
                printf("%s %d/%d/%d %d\n", array[i].regione, array[i].data.giorno, array[i].data.mese, array[i].data.anno, array[i].mm_pioggia);
                i++;
            }
               else exit(1);
        }
    }
    else exit(1);

    fclose(file); }
```

Comment: Please _do_ publish your code. No matter how bad it is [or how bad you think it is], this is better than _not_ showing it. We can only help you with what we see. There just isn't enough to work with, and many here will _not_ help you further without seeing the code you've already written. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and follow the links, particularly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: fist edit your post, it is barely readable. Then, what are your exact inputs, ouputs, and errors  ? Where is your code ? We can't guess what you wrote and execute.

Comment: Don’t describe the code, **show** the code.  Describing says ”this is basically what I’m telling the computer to do”.  Problem is, computers don’t do “basically” what you tell them, they do **exactly** what you tell them.  So tell us **exactly** what you’re telling the computer to do, i.e. **show your code**.

Comment: Ok i'll insert code my two try with fgets() and scanf() in first post. @LoneWanderer compiler don't gave me any error...

Comment: I post my code. Hope you can help me :)

Comment: The `while(1)` loop can simply be replaced with `while (fgets( buf,1000, file))`, The `if (feof(file)==0)` is unnecessary as you have just opened the file. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Those are just to make things a bit more readable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I use (feof(file)==0) to verify that is not empty. Is wrong?

Comment: `r = sscanf( buf, "%s% d/%d/%d %d\n",...` should be screaming warnings at you. `sscanf` returns `int`, but you declare `char *r`. And yes, `feof(file)==0)` is wrong and does not test if the file is empty. Just call `fgets` and check the return.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ok thanks for feof(file)==0. sscanf not return any error or warning. I use codeblock 17.12

Comment: Nothing wrong with CodeBlocks, that means you are probably using gcc/MinGW as the compiler -- it is a good compiler. Your `crea_array` function cannot be type `void` but must be type `tipo_dati_file *` and you must `return array;` at the end and assign it to a pointer back in `main()`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i know that , maybe in try i don't change it (don't remember) but it shouldn't cause crash in program right? I don't understand why it crash during fill array...

Answer (score 1):

You have two primary problems I see in `crea_array`,

1. You declare `char* r;` but then attempt to assign the return of `sscanf (buf, "%s %d/%d/%d %d\n", ...` (e.g. `r = sscanf (...`. This is incorrect. `sscanf` returns type `int` representing the number of successful conversions that took place as specified in your *format string* (e.g. `"%s %d/%d/%d %d\n"` would return `5` on success, and **remove the** `'\n'`, it will cause problems). Your compiler should be screaming warnings at you. If not, you need to enable compiler warnings by adding `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` as compiler options and *do not accept code until it compiles without a single warning*.
2. `crea_array` must be declared as type `tipo_dati_file *` and it must `return array;` at the end. You must assign the return to a pointer back in the caller. You must also `free (buf);` before the `return` or you have just created a *memory leak* as there is no way to `free()` the memory you allocated for `buf` after the function returns. (further, if you are simply allocating `1000-char` each time, just use a fixed buffer, e.g. `char buf[1000];` and eliminate the need to allocate `buf` completely.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#define MAXC 1000   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

tipo_dati_file *crea_array (char* Nome_f, int v) 
{
    int i = 0,
        s,
        r;
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    //tipo_ritorna risultati;
    FILE* file;

    //n = conta_righe(file);
    tipo_dati_file *array = malloc (v * sizeof *array);
    file = fopen (Nome_f, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf ("Errore in apertura del file!");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (!array) {   /* if you allocate, you must validate - every time */
        perror ("malloc-array");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, file) != NULL)
    {
        r = sscanf (buf, "%s %d/%d/%d %d", array[i].regione, 
                    &array[i].data.giorno, &array[i].data.mese, 
                    &array[i].data.anno, &array[i].mm_pioggia);

        if (r != 5) {   /* validate return of every (s)scanf funciton */
            fput ("error: failed to parse buf.\n", stderr);
            continue;   /* get next line */
        }

        printf ("%s %d/%d/%d %d\n", array[i].regione, array[i].data.giorno, 
                array[i].data.mese, array[i].data.anno, array[i].mm_pioggia);
        i++;
    }

    fclose (file);

    return array; 
}
```

**Note:** I have not compiled the code above.

Then in `main`, you could do something similar to:

```
tipo_dati_file *array = crea_array (name, v);
```

(**note:** you should also pass a 3rd parameter of type `int *numelem` so you can assign `*numelem = i;` before return making the number of elements filled available back in the caller if less than `v` are actually read)

If you will post a [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with a sample data file (10 lines or so), I'm happy to help further and I can validate the code works -- as I will have something I can compile and run.

**Edit Following Warnings Posted (in comments)**

The two warnings are addressed in detail in the comments below the answer. Once those are resolved, you will run into a horrible `SegFault` as you are not allocating storage for `array[i].regione`.

In you nested set of structs:

```
typedef struct dati_file_s {
    char* regione;
    tipo_data data;
    int mm_pioggia; 
} tipo_dati_file;
```

`regione` is an uninitialized pointer that points to some indeterminate memory location (which you do not own). When you attempt to write characters there with `sscanf` (BOOM - SegFault -- most likely).

You have two choices (1) declare `regione` as a fixed array, e.g. `char regione[CONST]` (inefficient), or (2) read the string for `regione` into a *temporary* buffer and then allocate storage for `strlen + 1` chars and copy the string from the temporary buffer to the new block of memory and assign the starting address for that block to `regione` (you can use `strlen/malloc/memcpy` or `strdup` -- if you have it, it does all three)

With that fix and a few tweaks to your `crea_array` function (like passing a pointer to `int` to hold the number of struct filled in `array` instead of `v`), you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC  1024  /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXDATA 64

typedef enum mese_e { Genv= 1, Feb, Mar, Apr, Mag, Giu, 
                        Lug, Ago, Set, Ott, Nov, Dic
} tipo_mese; 

typedef struct data_s {
    int giorno;
    tipo_mese mese;
    int anno;
} tipo_data;

typedef struct dati_file_s {
    char* regione;
    tipo_data data;
    int mm_pioggia; 
} tipo_dati_file;

typedef struct ritorna_s {
    tipo_dati_file* array;
    int count; 
} tipo_ritorna;

tipo_dati_file *crea_array (char *Nome_f, int *nelem) 
{
    int i = 0,
        r;
    char region[MAXC] = ""; /* temp buffer to hold array[i].regione */
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    FILE* file;

    tipo_dati_file *array = malloc (MAXDATA * sizeof *array);
    file = fopen (Nome_f, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf ("Errore in apertura del file!");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!array) {   /* if you allocate, you must validate - every time */
        perror ("malloc-array");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, file) != NULL)
    {
        r = sscanf (buf, "%s %d/%d/%d %d", region, 
                    &array[i].data.giorno, (int*)&array[i].data.mese, 
                    &array[i].data.anno, &array[i].mm_pioggia);

        if (r != 5) {   /* validate return of every (s)scanf funciton */
            fputs ("error: failed to parse buf.\n", stderr);
            continue;   /* get next line */
        }

        array[i].regione = strdup (region);
        if (!array[i].regione) {  /* strdup allocates - you must validate */
            perror ("strdup-array[i].regione");
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)     /* on failure free prior mem */
                free (array[j].regione);    /* and return NULL */
            free (array);
            return NULL;
        }

        i++;
    }

    fclose (file);

    *nelem = i;     /* update nelem with number of struct filled */

    return array; 
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int index = 0,
        nelem = 0;
    char *datafile = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "dat/staterain.txt";
    tipo_ritorna statistics[MAXDATA] = {{ .array = NULL }};

    statistics[index].array = crea_array (datafile, &nelem);

    if (statistics[index].array && nelem > 0) {
        statistics[index].count = nelem;
        for (int i = 0; i < statistics[index].count; i++) {
            printf ("%-12s   %02d/%02d/%4d   %3d\n", 
                    statistics[index].array[i].regione, 
                    statistics[index].array[i].data.giorno, 
                    statistics[index].array[i].data.mese, 
                    statistics[index].array[i].data.anno, 
                    statistics[index].array[i].mm_pioggia);
            free (statistics[index].array[i].regione);  /* free strings */
        }
        free (statistics[index].array); /* free array */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/staterain
Texas          03/03/2015     1
California     06/02/2013     5
Utah           03/01/2014    10
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/staterain
==3349== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3349== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3349== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3349== Command: ./bin/staterain
==3349==
Texas          03/03/2015     1
California     06/02/2013     5
Utah           03/01/2014    10
==3349==
==3349== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3349==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3349==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 2,110 bytes allocated
==3349==
==3349== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3349==
==3349== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3349== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks! 1) I'll correct that things. 2) Function not should return array but two things: array and count ((number of file's lines). For this reason i have created struct ritorna_s. But i don't know if is the right way to do it...

Comment: *" and do not accept code until it compiles without a single warning"* I could not agree more

Comment: I enable compiler warning and compiler give me 5 warning. 'C:\....Prova 4\stack overflow modifica.c:74:30: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format [-Wformat=]
                 sscanf( buf, "%s% d/%d/%d %d\n", array[i].regione, &array[i].data.giorno, &array[i].data.mese, &array[i].data.anno, &array[i].mm_pioggia);
                              ^
C:\....Prova 4\stack overflow modifica.c:74:30: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 5 has type 'tipo_mese * {aka enum mese_e *}' [-Wformat=]'

Comment: C:\....Prova 4\stack overflow modifica.c:74:30: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
C:\....Prova 4\stack overflow modifica.c:46:13: warning: unused variable 's' [-Wunused-variable]
     int i=0,s;
             ^

Comment: C:\....Prova 4\stack overflow modifica.c: In function 'main':
C:\....Prova 4\stack overflow modifica.c:130:28: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 3 has type 'tipo_mese * {aka enum mese_e *}' [-Wformat=]
                     scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &data.giorno, &data.mese, &data.anno);

Comment: I'll try to use your code but this part give me an error. I don't understand what do... Ho can resolve? 'if (r != 5) {   /* validate return of every (s)scanf funciton */
            fput ("error: failed to parse buf.\n", stderr);
            continue;   /* get next line */'

Comment: OK @Allister, I'm back. Give me a bit to digest all the new information.

Comment: That makes sense, you have `"% d"` - that causes: `"warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20"` see: [www.AsciiTable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/) - what character does hex `0x20` designate? (get rid of the space between `"% d"`) Next `"format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 5 has type 'tipo_mese * {aka enum mese_e *}'"` also self-explanatory `array[i].data.mese` is type `enum mese_e` not `int` so `sscanf` rightly warns, perhaps `(int*)&array[i].data.mese`. Give that a go and report back.